# Try - Catch Exception Java - Eclipse

Tags: java, try-catch

Well I want to use this try/catch in Java using the Execption in a program. Basically the program is aim to get the number/ amount of a certain product and it calculates its price and discount.

I want the `txtAmount` which is supposed to receive only numbers does not crash if put letters here is part of the code. Just a simple solution

```
public static String modelo, obsequio = null, resolucion = null;
    public static int amount, numgift = 0, resolution = 0;
    public static double amountourchase = 0, idiscount = 0, itopayr = 0, discount = 0, price = 0;

    protected void actionPerformedBtnSell(ActionEvent arg0) {
        inData();
        calculateDiscount();
        prrocessPurchase();
        Results();
    }

    void indata(){
        model = cboModelo.getSelectedItem().toString();
        amount = Integer.parseInt(txtCantidad.getText());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code:

```
try {
        double d = Double.parseDouble(your input is here);
         or
        int i =  Integer.parseInt(your input is here);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e) {
         System.out.print(e);

    }
```

Note: try to work on this I think the code in below is the one that you are looking for.

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Demo");
        f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        f.setSize(300, 200);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        JLabel label = new JLabel("enter your number: ");
        JTextField userText = new JTextField(6);
        JButton button = new JButton("OK");
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel();

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                try {
                    int i = Integer.parseInt(userText.getText());
                    label1.setText(Integer.toString(i));
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f,
                            "Input integer number ",
                            "NumberFormatException",
                            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    userText.setText("");
                }
            }
        });

        f.add(label);
        f.add(userText);
        f.add(button);
        f.add(label1);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
```

**Note** :
 you should define your amount and other variables in type double to be **more precise**

Comment: what about this new example to use in the code above int readNumber (){ int num; try { num = Integer.parseInt(txtNumero.getText()); } catch (Exception e) { num = -1 ; return num; { . Is it possible to implement in the code above?

Comment: let me see what you try to say?

Comment: what do you try to accomplish? cuz when you are in catch vlock and your return something. everything is gone. do you wanna ask the person to be in loop till he or she put the right format?

Comment: yes because if the person continue putting a letter put a number

Answer (score 1):

```
void indata() {
    model = cboModelo.getSelectedItem().toString();
    try {
        amount = Integer.parseInt(txtCantidad.getText());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // Handle it here
    }
}
```

Comment: what about this example to use  in the code above              int readNumber (){ int num; try { num = Integer.parseInt(txtNumero.getText()); } catch (Exception e) { num = -1 ; return num; { .  Is it possible to implement in the code abovve

Comment: I was just finishing typing this is an example apart